# Plotly offline, and dropdown widgets

Tags: python, plot, widget, plotly, jupyter

I have to create a graph with various curves to plot. My goal is to create a dropdown widget where I can select the curve I want to plot, i.e. choose the data my iplot is going to plot.

I am using Jupyter Notebook. I imported iplot and initialized notebook mode.

```
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
```

My x axis is always the same: `X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]`.

My y data is what I want to be able to change through the widget: I have a list of lists, and I want to be able to choose the index of the list I want to plot.

So far, I have a graph where I am ploting all the data and a dropdown widget that does nothing:

```
k=len(Y)

updatemenus = [
    {
        'buttons': [
            {
                'method': 'restyle',
                'label': str(i),
                'args': [
                    {},
                ]
            } for i in range(k)
        ],
        'direction': 'down',
        'showactive': True,
    }
]


iplot({
      'data':
           [{'x': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
             'y': Y[i],
             'name': str(i)
           } for i in range(k)],
      'layout': {'title': 'Title',
                'updatemenus': updatemenus}
  })
```

I have the sense that I have to write something in the 'args' of the `updatemenus`, but I can't find what it would be. I've tried things like `'y': Y[i]`, but it just plots a straight line as if there was no 'y' axis indicated in the iplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a solution, although it is probably not ideal: in the args option of updatemenus, I've now written `{'visible': [False]*i+[True]+[False]*(k-i-1)}`.

And for the graph to only plot the first curve when I execute the program, I've modified the iplot command like this :

```
iplot({
      'data':
           [{'x': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
             'y': Y[i],
             'name': str(i),
             'visible': i==0
           } for i in range(k)],
      'layout': {'title': 'Title',
                'updatemenus': updatemenus}
  })
```